# How to replace a range with list of coordinates in Excel?

Tags: excel, xlsx, xls

This code calculates a sum of string lengths in the `column C` which are in the same row with a number in `column B`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(B2:B1048576)*LEN(C2:C1048576))
```

[image]

If instead of `column C`I'd like to place a set of coorfinates which describes by the shift indexes in `column A` how should I change the range to coordinates?

[image]

I found that I can convert shift indexes to column letters to get a column coordinate for each row with this code:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1;H1;4);"1";"")
```

[image]

But I don't know how to use this set of coordinates instead of the `column range C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(INDEX(C:F,N(IF({1},ROW(B2:B6))),N(IF({1},A2:A6+1))))*ISNUMBER(B2:B6))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you explain a bit how this thing inside `LEN` function works?

Comment: `INDEX` takes three arguments, `INDEX(range,row,column)` I just create an array of rows and and array of columns(based on the index in column A) those get passed to the INDEX and the INDEX then returns the correct value at those indices.  If you use Formula→Evaluate Formula you can follow the steps.

Comment: What is the meaning of `{1}` in `IF({1}...`?

Comment: It forces an array.  If you have a subscription to Office 365 both the `N(IF({1},..))` are not needed as they fixed INDEX to take an array properly.  In all other versions we need to "trick" Index into accepting and using an array,  this is what that is doing.

Comment: I tested it and found that it returns 2 instead of 5 in Google Sheets. It counts incorrect value.

Comment: This will not work in Google-sheets.  They are different apps and have different abilities.

Comment: This happens because `INDEX` in Google Sheets returns a single value, not an array. Everything else works the same. Do you know another function which does the same as `INDEX`?